# Can a pipe in Linux ever lose data?

Tags: linux, posix, pipe

And is there an upper limit on how much data it can contain?

Comment: its lose not loose. loose is a loose tooth

Comment: @intuited: bad delimiter ")" (missing open parenthesis)

Comment: made my day, 4 more characters go :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Barring a machine crash, no it can't lose data.  It's easy to misuse it and think you're losing data however, either because a write failed to write all the data you requested and you didn't check the return value or you did something wrong with the read.

The maximum amount of data it can hold is system dependent -- if you try to write more than that, you'll either get a short write or the writer will block until space is available.  The `pipe(7)` man page contains lots of useful info about pipes, including (on Linux at least) how big the buffer is.  Linux has buffers of 4K or 64K depending on version.

**edit**

Tim mentions SIGPIPE, which is also a potential issue that can seem to lose data.  If the reader closes the pipe before reading everything in it, the unread data will be thrown away and the writer will get a SIGPIPE signal when they write more or close the pipe, indicating that this has occurred.  If they block or ignore the SIGPIPE, they'll get an EPIPE error.  This covers the situation Paul mentioned.

`PIPE_BUF` is a constant that tells you the limit of *atomic* writes to the buffer.  Any write this size or smaller will either succeed completely or block until it can succeed completely (or give EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN if the pipe is in non-blocking mode).  It has no relation to the actual size of the kernel's pipe buffer, though obviously the buffer must be at least PIPE_BUF in size to meet the atomicity guarentee.

Comment: I actually abandoned my answer after loading this one. You may want to mention SIGPIPE, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGPIPE

Comment: There might be a scenario where you kill the writer or the reader so the writer thinks it's written something that the reader hasn't read?

Comment: PIPE_BUF in limits.h will tell you how big the limit is. sysconf() with _PC_PIPE_BUF can tell you at runtime (on linux anyway)

Answer (score 3):

Data can be lost in a pipe when the following happens:

1. A process (the writer) writes n bytes of data to the pipe, where n≤`PIPE_BUF`. This write is guaranteed to be atomic and will never block.
2. A process (the reader) reads only m<n bytes of data and exits.
3. The writer doesn’t attempt to write to the pipe again.

As a result, the kernel pipe buffer will contain n-m bytes which will be lost when all handles to the pipe have been closed. The writer will not see `SIGPIPE` or `EPIPE` since it never attempts to write to the pipe again. Since the writer won’t ever learn that the pipe contains leftover data that will simply disappear, one can consider this data lost.

A non-standard way of detecting this would be for the writer to define a timeout and call the `FIONREAD` ioctl to determine the number of bytes left in the pipe buffer.

Comment: Shouldn't that be FIONREAD? Note on Linux at least FIONREAD indicates how much data is unread on the write descriptor (stdout for example), but doesn't seem to indicate the reader has gone away. It seems useful to me if there was a mode to have the kernel send a SIGPIPE to the writer if the reader went away without reading all of the data

Comment: Thanks, fixed the typo. Indeed, `FIONREAD` doesn’t indicate whether the reader has gone away, hence the need to define a time-out. Yea, I would also find it useful if `SIGPIPE` were sent.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to using the `|` operator in the shell then no, it will not lose data.  It merely connects the app on the left side's standard output stream to the app on the right side's standard input stream.  If you are piping data between apps and aren't getting the results you expect, try using `>` to redirect standard output from the first app to a file and then use `<` to use that file as standard input for the second app.  That way, you can inspect the file amd make sure the data is being sent in the format you expect.

If you mean a pipe created by the `pipe` function then the answer is still no.  According to [this man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe), writing to a full pipe will block until enough data has been read to make room for the write data.  It also states that the size of a pipe is 4KB in Linux pre-2.6.11, and is 64kB on 2.6.11 and later.

Answer (score 2):

Your pipe isn't losing data.  If you're losing data in your application, try debugging it with gdb.
A couple of things to look for: 
1) Is your buffer large enough to hold all the data that you're reading? 
2) Check the return codes from your read() on the pipe for errors. 
3) Are you sure you're writing all of the data to the pipe? 
4) Is your write/read operation getting interrupted by a signal?  ie: SIGPIPE?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you will not lose data is that when the buffer associated with the pipe fills up a call to `write` will block until the reader has emptied the buffer enough for the operation to complete.  (You can do non-blocking writes as well, but then you are responsible for making sure you complete any writes that would have blocked.)