# Stop accepting input on pipe but read buffered data

Tags: ruby, linux

I've got an application which reads from `$stdin` and does some processing on the data. I want to put in a signal handler to catch SIGINT/SIGTERM and shutdown gracefully (meaning finish processing the data and exit when done). The tricky part is that I want it to stop reading from STDIN but be able to process any buffered data. This is so that another application can be launched and passed the same STDIN pipe and resume processing where the previous application left off.

The problem is that if I close STDIN, whatever was buffered is lost, or at least inaccessible.

Basically I'm trying this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

Signal.trap('INT') do
    $stdin.close
end

f = File.open('/tmp/out', 'a')
while (data = $stdin.read(4096)) != "" do
    f.write(data)
end
```

It immediately gives an `IOError` exception on the `$stdin.read` call, even though I know it read some data (strace shows it).

*(I don't need to close the pipe, I'm just doing it to break the `while` loop. If there's a more elegant way to break the loop and get the buffered data, I'd happily accept it.)*

---

I know this methodology works on the operating system level (pipe buffer is preserved when passed to another application) as I can do the following test and no data is lost:

```
# source.rb
i = 0
loop do
    puts "%08d" % (i += 1)
end
```

.

```
# reader.rb
$stdout.write($stdin.read(9))
$stdin.close
```

.

```
ruby /tmp/source.rb | while true; do ruby reader.rb; sleep 1; done
00000001
00000002
00000003
00000004
00000005
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen during the time between closing your end of the pipe and opening a new process? What if clients keep shoving data into the pipe while nothing is listening?  This isn't how pipes work. If you need a more resilient mechanism you may have to use a message-queueing system instead.

Comment: @JimGarrison It's supposed to buffer the data. That's *exactly* how pipes work (at least in linux, I can't speak for other operating systems). Edit: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715324/can-a-pipe-in-linux-ever-lose-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with this for a few days, I ended up having to drop `IO.read` and use `IO.sysread` instead and do my own buffering. The solution with this really isn't that complex, and below is the implementation.

```
Signal.trap('INT') do
    $stdin.close
end

def myread(bufio, bytes) # `bufio` is a StringIO object, `bytes` is bytes to read
    begin
        while bufio.size < bytes do
            bufio.write($stdin.sysread(bytes - bufio.size))
        end
    rescue SignalException, Interrupt, Errno::EINTR => e
        retry
    rescue SystemCallError, IOError, EOFError => e
        # nothing, we're done
    end
end
```

---

My exact code is a little different from that as I'm using the AWS ruby SDK, so that `myread` method is actually just a block passed to `AWS::S3::S3Object.write`

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be to dup the file descriptor before closing the original, then the error will break the loop, and you can read the rest of the data from the unclosed duplicate file handle.

(Sorry if this code is bad, I don't know ruby)

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'fcntl'

stdin_dup = nil

Signal.trap('INT') do
  stdin_dup = File.for_fd($stdout.fcntl(Fcntl::F_DUPFD))
  $stdin.close
end

f = File.open('/tmp/out', 'a')
begin
  while (data = $stdin.read(4096)) != "" do
    f.write(data)
  end
rescue IOError
  # finish stuff with stdin_dup here
end
```

Comment: Your example code has you duping `$stdout`. However when I try it on `$stdin` I still get the exception because the previous `$stdin.read()` call was still pending when the pipe was closed. Also when I dup STDIN and use the dup'd object, I can still read from the incoming stream. I don't want to read any more data from the stream, just grab what's sitting on the buffer.

Comment: @Patrick In that case, there are no (to my knowledge) primitives that can help you do what you want. The shell example you gave with the pipe going to multiple programs is just dup'd, it's not actually doing anything different than this example. I was more aiming for your comment about breaking out of the loop, but I may have misinterpreted it.

Comment: @Patrick you can't get the buffered data without just trying to read it as fast as possible (non-blocking, so you know when the end is). This has the problem that it may never end though, as the pipe may be refilled faster than it's emptied.

Comment: Also, fixed the stdin/stdout mistakes, not sure how that happened.